# Regular expression for matching a string and replace

Tags: regex

I am trying to create a pattern for matching and replacing the words using regex.
My string is like given below

```
<mycomponent id="Myvalue1.Myvalue2.013D0E13-BF5F-4D0F-AAFA-FA4B120DE3E9"
<mycomponent id="Myvalue3.Myvalue4.013D0E13-BF5F-4D0F-AAFA-FA4B120DE3E9"
<mycomponent id="Myvalue5.Myvalue6.013D0E13-BF5F-4D0F-AAFA-FA4B120DE3E9"
<mycomponent id="Myvalue7.Myvalue8.013D0E13-BF5F-4D0F-AAFA-FA4B120DE3E9"
```

I want the expected result to be look like

```
<mycomponent id="Myvalue1.Myvalue2"
<mycomponent id="Myvalue3.Myvalue4"
<mycomponent id="Myvalue5.Myvalue6"
<mycomponent id="Myvalue7.Myvalue8"
```

I can't use ReplaceAll .013D0E13-BF5F-4D0F-AAFA-FA4B120DE3E9 to empty because there are some features that are still using that GUID

I was able to match the string using below pattern

```
  <mycomponent Id=*.*.013D0E13-BF5F-4D0F-AAFA-FA4B120DE3E9
```

But when i used the below pattern for replacing it is not working

```
 <mycomponent Id=*.*.
```

Comment: what programming language is used in your case?

Comment: i am trying to replace value using Notepad++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That pattern doesn't really do the intended thing, since you haven't escaped the dots. That's just a coincidence. To match what you want, the following regex should be used.

```
<mycomponent id=.*?\..*?\.
```

This regex matches `<mycomponent id=`, then a dot, then the minimal amount of chars before it meets a dot, then a dot, then again the minimal amount of chars before it meets another dot.

---

If you would like to repalce, use this for the regex field

```
(<mycomponent id=".*?\..*?)\.\S+
```

and this for the replace field

```
$1"
```

Comment: and for replacing what regex should i use

Comment: @user What would you like to replace, and with what?

Comment: it is mentioned in the question.Could you please look that

Comment: @user It isn't. You just said that you're not going to remove the ids with replaceAll.

Comment: @user Do you want to remove the GUID or `<mycomponent id=Myvalue1.Myvalue2`?

Comment: i want to remove GUID

Comment: Thanks nicael.it's working
What to do if i want to keep the quotes ""

Comment: @user I've added the support for quotes, check it.

Comment: What to do if i have a single dot in the string 
<mycomponent id="Myvalue1.013D0E13-BF5F-4D0F-AAFA-FA4B120DE3E9".
I gave the search string like
(<mycomponent id=".*?\.013D0E13-BF5F-4D0F-AAFA-FA4B120DE3E9)\S+ and able to match but the replace with $1 pattern is not working

Answer (score 1):

Use the following approach:

- regexp field(search for):

  ```
  (<mycomponent id=.+\..+)(?:\.)013D0E13-BF5F-4D0F-AAFA-FA4B120DE3E9(.+)
  ```
- replace to:

  ```
  $1$2
  ```

(tested on `Notepad++`)

Comment: It is working. But i just want to replace the GUILD. This pattern is replacing everything after the GUID too.

Comment: you have not presented the actual string which contain something *after the GUID*. Add some example

Comment: My full string is like 

<mycomponent id=Myvalue1.Myvalue2.013D0E13-BF5F-4D0F-AAFA-FA4B120DE3E9 Name="test.DLL" Path="nil" verbose="no">

Comment: I doubt OP has the same GUID everywhere. This solution is not really flexible.

Comment: Yes Nicael,GUID is same everywhere