# Regex to replace string in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

Hi i am trying to write a regular expression for matching and replacing below strings using Notepad++

```
<mycomponent id="Myvalue1.013D0E13-BF5F-4D0F-AAFA-FA4B120DE3E9" test="my" value="1234"/>
<mycomponent id="Myvalue3.013D0E13-BF5F-4D0F-AAFA-FA4B120DE3E9" kv="ggg" propert="null"/>
<mycomponent id="Myvalue5.013D0E13-BF5F-4D0F-AAFA-FA4B120DE3E9" fff="ddd" key="kk"/>
<mycomponent id="Myvalue7.013D0E13-BF5F-4D0F-AAFA-FA4B120DE3E9" dfd="drgf"/>
```

I want to replace 013D0E13-BF5F-4D0F-AAFA-FA4B120DE3E9 from these string and result should be as given below

```
  <mycomponent id="Myvalue1" test="my" value="1234"/>
 <mycomponent id="Myvalue3" kv="ggg" propert="null"/>
   <mycomponent id="Myvalue5" fff="ddd" key="kk"/>
<mycomponent id="Myvalue7" dfd="drgf"/>
```

I used the below RE for matching and replacing

```
(<mycomponent id=".*?\.013D0E13-BF5F-4D0F-AAFA-FA4B120DE3E9)\S+
```

as the find sting and $1 as the replace string. Eventhought the find is working the replace is not working

Comment: Hello Nicael.

What i tried is given in the question. Could you please tell me what is wrong

Comment: Is it an XML document with valid XML structure?

Comment: It's really basically the same as I've mentioned in [my previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38645907). Just remove the first `.*?\.` and you have this question answered.

Comment: yes its an xml document

Comment: hello Nicael, I already tried it but it is replacing the Quotes too
(<mycomponent id=".*?)\.\S+

Comment: But you should use the same `$1"`, while you're using `$1`.

Comment: Btw, since you've got the same key everywhere, why don't you just use `.013D0E13-BF5F-4D0F-AAFA-FA4B120DE3E9` for find and nothing for replace?

Comment: no i can't because the same GUID with dot is used somewhere after the line itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find What:  `(<mycomponent.*?)[.]013D0E13-BF5F-4D0F-AAFA-FA4B120DE3E9`

Replace with : `$1`

search mode : Regular Expression

It will also work for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38645844/regular-expression-for-matching-a-string-and-replace)

And if you want to make it more general for other unique identifiers:

Find What: `(<mycomponent.*?id="[^"]*?)[.][A-Fa-f0-9\-]{36}`
Replace with : `$1`